# Load multiple AID configuration

Tags: emv, pos

Is it possible to load multiple AID configurations for the same AID on the terminal/POS, one for chip and one for contactless cards?
If so, how can the card determine which one to use?

Example: for a Mastercard (A0000000041010) set different terminal floor limits, different TAC, and so on.

Comment: How about registering on this site and checking it out? [EMVCo LLC.](https://www.emvco.com/) Or, even if you are not registered, you can check this much, so why not follow the results? [Document Search](https://www.emvco.com/document-search/?action=search_documents&publish_date=&emvco_document_version=&emvco_document_book=&px_search=AID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many parameters are depending on device capabilities, used CVMs, transaction environment, etc. Those are usually different for contact and contactless and you set them for kernels individually. The card does not need to know the difference, the selected kernel for this interface and this particular transaction will know which of the configurations should be used (AID and transaction initiation interface may not be the only differentiators).

The answer to your question is not generic and does not apply to all terminals. There are different ways of configuring parameters for different vendors. Some use API interface you set before transaction, some use callbacks during transaction, some use files and there is multitude of formats. There is no standard for a way how configuration is supplied to the kernel and you need to refer to your vendor documentation for the answer.